# Segue to a tableview Controller, passing data over

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, segue

Swift 3.0 iOS 10.x

Segue to a TableViewController, passed the data over; but it doesn't display correctly; I see the first data row twice? [Just two rows of data passed over].

TableView looks like this.. boiler plate code more or less.

```
import UIKit

class QRtableViewController: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var beaconArray:[String] = []

@IBOutlet var beaconTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleTap))
    // 4
    recognizer.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    print("beaconArray II \(beaconArray)")

    beaconTable.delegate = self
    beaconTable.dataSource = self
    beaconTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "theCell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
    print("Value: \(beaconArray[indexPath.row])")
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return beaconArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "theCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(beaconArray[indexPath.row])"
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed", size: 6)
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    return cell
}
}
```

And segue to TVC looks like this...

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "beaconList", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewControllerB = segue.destination as? QRtableViewController {
        print("\(beaconArray)")
        viewControllerB.beaconArray = beaconArray
    }
}
```

Checked beaconArray both before I pass it across and after. Looks ok?

```
beaconArray I["Venus CLBeacon (uuid:2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFC4, major:4, minor:1, proximity:3 +/- 7.25m, rssi:-80)", "Mars CLBeacon (uuid:2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA2, major:1, minor:7, proximity:3 +/- 4.64m, rssi:-78)"]
beaconArray II ["Venus CLBeacon (uuid:2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFC4, major:4, minor:1, proximity:3 +/- 7.25m, rssi:-80)", "Mars CLBeacon (uuid:2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA2, major:1, minor:7, proximity:3 +/- 4.64m, rssi:-78)"]
```

But I get this?

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: both look same even before. whats the difference

Comment: `UITableViewController` has an implicit `tableView` instance with connected datasource and delegate. Why do you create another one?

Comment: First line should read.. Venus CLBeacon (uuid:2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFC4.... and second line Mars CLBeacon (uuid:2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911....

Comment: Commented out the data source and delegate calls; didn't complain; thanks, but still shows only the first row in the data source? Tried with more data; 5 lines; segue TVC only shows the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two delegate methods. It's supposed to be

```
// override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
//    return 1
// }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return beaconArray.count
}
```

The default value of `numberOfSections` is 1 so it can be omitted.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Will tick the ticker when it lets me :)

Comment: And if you are using prototype cells don't register the cell. (Unfortunately many tutorials suggest that nonsense)

Comment: Bon, removed the registration too! and it still works :)